# Pushing a field and a method to mixin ruined the program

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

**Django==1.11.4**

This model worked fine:

```
class File(CommonUrlMethodsMixin,
           ItemIsMainMixin,
           models.Model):

    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    user_file = models.FileField(blank=False,
                                 max_length=255,
                                 upload_to=get_file_path,
                                 verbose_name=_("file"))

    def __str__(self):
        if self.user_file.name:
            str_repr = "{}:{}".format(str(self.id), self.user_file.name)
        else:
            str_repr = str(self.id)
        return str_repr
```

But then I wanted to add another model that also has a FileField. The new model will look quite similar to this one. The only difference will be the foreign key.

I did like this:

```
class GeneralFileMixin():
    user_file = models.FileField(blank=False,
                                 max_length=255,
                                 upload_to=get_file_path,
                                 verbose_name=_("file"))

    def __str__(self):
        if self.user_file.name:
            str_repr = "{}:{}".format(str(self.id), self.user_file.name)
        else:
            str_repr = str(self.id)
        return str_repr    


class File(CommonUrlMethodsMixin,
           ItemIsMainMixin,
           GeneralFileMixin,
           models.Model):

    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

I made migrations.

**forms.py**

```
class FileForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = File
        exclude = []
        widgets = {
            'item': forms.HiddenInput()
        }
```

**views.py**

```
class FileCreate(LoginRequiredMixin,
                 CreateView):
    model = File
    form_class = FileForm
```

But now the FileCreate doesn't show the input field for a file.

Well, the migration is here:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('files', '0004_auto_20170831_0917'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='file',
            name='user_file',
        ),
    ]
```

Well, it really removed user_file. But why didn't it take into account the user_file from the mixin?

Well, could you give me a kick here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your new mixin should be inherit of `models` and need add `abstarct=True`

```
class GeneralFileMixin(models.Model):
    #                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    user_file = models.FileField(blank=False,
                                 max_length=255,
                                 upload_to=get_file_path,
                                 verbose_name=_("file"))

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
    #   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    def __str__(self):
        if self.user_file.name:
            str_repr = "{}:{}".format(str(self.id), self.user_file.name)
        else:
            str_repr = str(self.id)
        return str_repr
```